# Unresolved external symbol when linking to static lib with namespace

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I ran into a behavior today that I don't completely understand. I jump right into a minimal code example and will explain along the way.

I have 2 Projects: A static c++ library and a console application.

**Static Lib Project:**

*Library.h*

```
#pragma once

namespace foo
{
    int testFunc();

    class StaticLibClass
    {
    public:
        static int testMemberFunc();
    };

}
```

*Library.cpp*

```
#include "Library.h"

using namespace foo;

// just some functions that don't do much
int testFunc()
{
    return 10;
}

int StaticLibClass::testMemberFunc()
{
    return 11;
}
```

**Console Application Project:**

*main.cpp*

```
#include "library.h"

using namespace foo;

void main()
{
    // calling this function reslts in LNK2019: unresolved external symbol...
    testFunc();

    // this function works just fine
    StaticLibClass::testMemberFunc();
}
```

As you can see the static member function of a class works just fine. The single testFunc however results in a linker error. Why is this?

The solution to the problem is to not use "using" in the Library.cpp file but also wrap it in the namespace like so:

**Changes that fix the problem:**

*Library.cpp*

```
#include "Library.h"

namespace foo
{

    // just some functions that don't do much
    int testFunc()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    int StaticLibClass::testMemberFunc()
    {
        return 11;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a declaration for foo::testFunc() but a definition for ::testFunc().  The linker complains because it cannot find foo::testFunc()

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It is somewhat a duplicate but they don't really talk about namespaces in that question thread. I personally wouldn't have found the cause of my problem from reading the thread you linked.

Comment: @Hans How come the StaticLibClass is in the namespace then? And if I do the implementation in the console application the "using namespace" is enough for the compiler to know which function I'm implementing.

Comment: @derkie `using namespace X;` means that when you are doing *name lookup* -- i.e. looking to see where a name was declared -- then `X` is searched. However when you are declaring (or defining) a function, there is no name lookup.    Your last question is like asking : `using namespace std; int k;` - why didn't this declare `std::k` ?

Comment: I see, so the reason the class works is because i declare the class in the header file inside of the namespace block. But when using plain functions that don't belong to a class already you have to explicitly define the namespace. So I guess classes and namespaces are kinda similar in that manner, when implementing a class member function you always have to add the class "void ClassName::function()".

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: please stop downvoting and close voting everything has the expression "unresolved external symbol" with that clearly bad "canonical duplicate". This is not constructive.. Even if it manages to get closed, I will instantly reopen it with the binding reopen vote.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/819272) provided by @πάνταῥεῖ has the cause (first of three bullets: "Function/variable declared in one namespace, defined in another"), same as explained by Hans Passant

Comment: @FinalContest you should read the linked answer, my comment above and Hans Passants comment. It *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you TemplateRex, you're right. I must have missed that one bullet point before since I didn't completely understand that defining a function while 'using namespace' doesn't define it in that same namespace. So there was a fundamental misunderstanding about namespaces on my part which doesn't really relate to the whole 'unresolved external' problem.

Comment: @TemplateRex: read and reopened accordingly. We need precise and concise answers, not a lot of reading for a very simple issue that may be there in the Xth paragraph of the Yth answer. This is time-consuming. Furthermore, duplicates are for questions, not answers. On a side note, +1 to the question and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to wrap the body of the implementation functions/methods in a namespace statement that matches the original header, or you can use fully qualified names which is probably better C++ style:

```
#include "Library.h"

// just some functions that don't do much
int foo::testFunc()
{
    return 10;
}

int foo::StaticLibClass::testMemberFunc()
{
    return 11;
}
```

You don't need a using namespace foo; in this version. You are already in the namespace 'foo' when implementing the body's of those two methods, but it can be convenient depending on other types in that namespace.